# How safe are PDO prepared statement?

Tags: pdo, sql-injection

I'm wondering if PDO prepared statements can save me from SQL Injection ?

Example:
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

## The data I want to insert

$data = array( 'name' => $userInput_1, 'addr' => $userInput_2, 'city' => $userinput_3 );

## For instance $userInput_2 is SLQ INJECTION.

$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) value (:name, :addr, :city)");

## What will happen after execute in this case ?

$STH->execute($data);

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

All input will be properly escaped & quoted. So using PDO prepare / execute should prevent SQL Injection.

From the php manual:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that
>   will be issued multiple times with different parameter values
>   optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver
>   to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and
>   meta information, **and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by
>   eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.**

Comment: thanks. But will I get exception or the value will be populated into DB ?

Comment: It depends, strings will be escaped, but a null value will prevent the query from being executed. The result of `$STH -> execute($data)` will be FALSE  
`$data = array( 'name' => null, 'addr' => "1' AND 1=1", 'city' => false );  $data = array( 'name' => 'null', 'addr' => "1' AND 1=1", 'city' => 'false' );`  First one will fail, second one will succeed